# Math Input Panel for Windows XP?

Tags: microsoft-word, tablet, math-input-panel

Windows 7 has a cool applet called [Math Input Panel](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/23/ink-input-and-tablet.aspx).

Does anyone know if a version of this is available for Windows XP?

Comment: Upgrade! You won't regret it.

Answer (score 9):

[Microsoft Equation Writer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d346916-b526-487e-919d-0bce568def39&displaylang=en) which comes as part of the education pack.

[image]